# Can I make an image sequence in processing move/play with an Arduino ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, image-processing, arduino, processing

This is my first post so I apologize in advance if anything is unclear and I will try to learn quickly. I am also a newbie when it comes to programming. Using Arduino Uno, Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04, Processing3.5.3

In the processing and Arduino sketches I have provided I am able to play an image sequence, and when the ultrasonic sensor picks up the distance of an object a "1" is printed in the processing console.

I am wondering if I can use this "1" to make an if statement. If the console prints a number larger than 0, then have the image sequence play--else, only one image will be drawn (The gif will pause). I have tried a couple versions of this, but I don't want to pretend like I know what I am doing.

Any leads for me to follow would be wonderful! Or tutorials online!

I feel like there is something incredibly simple that I am just missing...
I guess nothing is ever that simple.
Thank you for your time :))

**ARDUINO CODE:**

```cpp
#define trigPin 9
#define echoPin 10

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  long distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);           //CHANGE THIS??
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  distance = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  if (distance <= 2000) { //raise this number to raise the distance to wave hand
    Serial.print("1");
  } else {
    Serial.print("0");
  }
  delay(500);  
}
```

**PROCESSING**

```cpp
import processing.serial.*;

int numFrames = 22; //number of frames in animation
int currentFrame = 0;
PImage[] image = new PImage[22];
Serial myPort;
String instring = "";

void setup() {
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600);
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
  size(1600, 900);
  frameRate(30);
  background(0);
  
  //Load images below
  for(int i = 0; i<image.length; i++) {
    image[i] = loadImage("PatMovingFace" + i + ".png");
  }
}

void draw() {
  //ALL BELOW connects to arduino sensor
  while (myPort.available () > 0) {
    instring = myPort.readString();
    println(instring);
    int sensorAct = Integer.parseInt(instring, 10);
  }
  playGif();   
}

// ALL BELOW will make the pic array animate! Image moves! 

void playGif() {
  currentFrame = (currentFrame+1) % numFrames; //use % to cycle through frames!
  int offset = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    //image(image[i] % numFrames), 0, 0);
    image(image[(currentFrame + offset) % numFrames], 0, 0);
    offset += 0;
    image(image[(currentFrame + offset) % numFrames], 0, 0);
    offset+= 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You already have the number you're after in the variable sensorAct.  Go ahead and use it in an if statement.  What's the hangup?

Comment: Great that you added this important info.

Comment: Find your own online tutorials.  That is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simpify / cleanup `playGif()` first:

- `offset` doesn't seem to do anything at the moment (it "increments" from 0 to 0)
- `image()` is called twice with the same coordinates overdrawing the same content on top of itself. once `image()` call should do
- you probably don't need the for loop since you're drawing one frame at a time
- `currentFrame` is increment to the next frame and loops back to the start at the start of `playGif()`, however, when rendering the image, the array index is incremented by `offset` (0) again. it's unclear what the intention is. you can do without
- `currentFrame` can control play/pause: if it increments it plays, otherwise it's paused. it's good to have a separation between updating data (`currentFrame`) and rendering with updated data (`image(image[currentFrame],0,0)`)
- you could also rename the `image` array to `images` so it's more representative of what it is and it's harder to get confused between that and the `image()` function

For example `playGif()` could turn to:

```java
void playGif(){
      currentFrame = (currentFrame+1) % numFrames; //use % to cycle through frames!
      image(image[currentFrame], 0, 0);
}
```

Regarding control using Arduino, as mentioned above, simply check if you get a "1" to update `currentFrame` (otherwise it will stay(paused) at the same value):

```java
void playGif(){
      if(instring.equals("1")){
         currentFrame = (currentFrame+1) % numFrames; //use % to cycle through frames!
      }
      image(image[currentFrame], 0, 0);
}
```

I'm using `equals()` above, because it's a `String`, even though you are sending a single character. (alternatively comparing the first character would've worked `if(instring.charAt(0) == '1')` )

I have a few notes on that as well:

- in the Arduino code you use `print()`, not `println()`, which means no `\n` will be sent, hence no need for `myPort.bufferUntil('\n');` nor `instring = myPort.readString();`
- you can read a single character with `myPort.read();` (which you can by the way compare with `==` (instead of String's `equals()`) (e.g. `if(myPort.read() == '1'){...`)
- `while` is blocking and I recommend not using it. It won't make a huge difference in your case since you're sending a single byte, but on more complex programs that send more bytes this will block Processing from rendering a single frame until it's received all the data

Here's an example:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

int numFrames = 22; //number of frames in animation
int currentFrame = 0;
PImage[] images = new PImage[numFrames];
Serial myPort; 

void setup() {
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[1], 9600);  
  
  size(1600, 900);                                    
  frameRate(30);                                      
  background(0);

  //Load images below
  for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++)
  { 
    images[i] = loadImage("PatMovingFace" + i + ".png");
  }
}

void draw() {
  // if there's at least one byte to read and it's '1'
  if(myPort.available() > 0 && myPort.read() == '1'){
    // increment frame, looping to the start
    currentFrame = (currentFrame+1) % numFrames; //use % to cycle through frames!
  }
  // render current frame
  image(images[currentFrame], 0, 0);
}
```

A more cautious version, checking for what coould go wrong (serial connection, data loading) would look like this:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
    
int numFrames = 22; //number of frames in animation
int currentFrame = 0;
PImage[] images = new PImage[numFrames];
Serial myPort; 

void setup() {
  String[] ports = Serial.list();
  int portIndex = 1;
  if(ports.length <= portIndex){
    println("serial ports index " + portIndex + " not found! check cable connection to Arduino");
    println("total ports: " + ports.length);
    printArray(ports);
    exit();
  }
  try{
    myPort = new Serial(this, ports[portIndex], 9600);  
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error connecting to serial port: double check the cable is connected and no other program (e.g. Serial Monitor) uses this port");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }  
  size(1600, 900);                                    
  frameRate(30);                                      
  background(0);

  //Load images below
  try{
    for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++)
    { 
      images[i] = loadImage("PatMovingFace" + i + ".png");
    }
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("image loading error");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

void draw() {
  // if Arduino connection was successfull
  if(myPort != null){
    // if there's at least one byte to read and it's '1'
    if(myPort.available() > 0 && myPort.read() == '1'){
      // increment frame, looping to the start
      currentFrame = (currentFrame+1) % numFrames; //use % to cycle through frames!
    }
  }else{
    text("serial port not initialised", 10, 15);
  }
  
  if(images[currentFrame] != null){
    // render current frame
    image(images[currentFrame], 0, 0);
  }else{
    text("serial port not loaded", 10, 15);
  }
}
```

or with the same thing in grouped using functions:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

int numFrames = 22; //number of frames in animation
int currentFrame = 0;
PImage[] images = new PImage[numFrames];

final int SERIAL_PORT_INDEX = 1;
final int SERIAL_BAUD_RATE  = 9600;
Serial myPort; 

void setup() {
  size(1600, 900);                                    
  frameRate(30);                                      
  background(0);
  
  setupArduino();
  //Load images below
  loadImages();
}

void setupArduino(){
  String[] ports = Serial.list();
  int numSerialPorts = ports.length;
  // optional debug prints: useful to double check serial connection 
  println("total ports: " + numSerialPorts);
  printArray(ports);
  // exit if requested port is not found  
  if(numSerialPorts <= SERIAL_PORT_INDEX){
    println("serial ports index " + SERIAL_PORT_INDEX + " not found! check cable connection to Arduino");
    //exit();
  }
  // try to open port, exit otherwise
  try{
    myPort = new Serial(this, ports[SERIAL_PORT_INDEX], SERIAL_BAUD_RATE);  
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error connecting to serial port: double check the cable is connected and no other program (e.g. Serial Monitor) uses this port");
    e.printStackTrace();
    //exit();
  }
}

void loadImages(){
  try{
    for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++)
    { 
      images[i] = loadImage("PatMovingFace" + i + ".png");
    }
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("image loading error");
    e.printStackTrace();
    //exit();
  }
}

void serialUpdateImage(){
  // if Arduino connection was successfull
  if(myPort != null){
    // if there's at least one byte to read and it's '1'
    if(myPort.available() > 0 && myPort.read() == '1'){
      // increment frame, looping to the start
      currentFrame = (currentFrame+1) % numFrames; //use % to cycle through frames!
    }
  }else{
    text("serial port not initialised", 10, 15);
  }
}

void displayCurrentImage(){
  if(images[currentFrame] != null){
    // render current frame
    image(images[currentFrame], 0, 0);
  }else{
    text("image " + currentFrame + " not loaded", 10, 25);
  }
}

void draw() {
  
  serialUpdateImage();
  
  displayCurrentImage();
}
```

Comment: You are a saint! I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help and explanation. Thank you.

Comment: A pleasure. I also have a cheeky plug: if you want to make your life easier loading/display image sequences you can try the [Image Sequence Player](https://github.com/hirschandmann/image-sequence-player) library I developed at Hirsch & Mann :) Good luck with your projects